# How to copy/rename a file and return it without altering the existing file?

Tags: java, file-io

I have a generic.exe file which doesn't contain any users detail in it.
I also have a REST API which takes the userId and returns a File to the client.

Now, what we want to implement in our project is that when someone hits the REST API, we want to take that generic.exe and rename it to manager_userId.exe and return back this "manager_userId.exe".

Points to be noted over here is that:

1. The generic.exe file should not be modified/deleted at all
2. When 2 users (userA and userB) hit that same API simultaneously , they should get their own copy of manager_userA.exe and manager_userB.exe

The code what I have written is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExecutable", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
@ResponseBody
public Response downloadExecutable(@RequestBody DownloadExecutableRequest downloadExecutableRequest,
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    File file = downloadExecutable(downloadExecutableRequest, request, response,
            getUserID(request), osDetails);
    return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.getName()).build();
}

public File downloadExecutable(DownloadExecutableRequest downloadExecutableRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String userId, String osDetails) {
        File file = null;
        String path = "/home/genericCopy/generic.exe";
        synchronized (this) {
            BufferedWriter fileWriter = null;
            try {
             File source = null;
             source = new File(path);
             Path destination = Paths.get("/tmp/");
             Files.copy(source, destination.toFile());
             fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(destination.getFileName().toString()+"_"+userId));
                 file = new File(destination.getFileName().toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } finally {
                if (fileWriter != null) {
                        fileWriter.close();
                }
            }
                        
        }
        return file;
    }
```

The code is working , but it is creating a temporary file and then renaming it and then returning it back but it will keep on creating the copies of the file for each request.
Is there any smarter way that i can achieve not to create such temporary copies of the user specific files and also handle a scenario when 2 users hit the API simultaneously ?

Comment: Why do you copy the original file at all? Just set the content disposition to the name you want it downloaded as, and return the template file.

Comment: Side comment: Are you really requiring your users to download and execute a dynamically generated executable?  Do you understand the security risk to the users' systems?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file which is downloaded by user has no relationship to the name of the file on disk.

You can just specify any name of the file in the header and the user will see the name.

Specifically, you would just set the filename you want the user to see to the `Content-Disposition` header and always load the same exe file from the disk.

Something like this:

```
return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=executable_" + getUserID(request) + ".exe";
```

You don't need to do any copying in the `downloadExecutable` function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a copy of `generic.exe` file to return it with changed name. You can use correctly parametrised `Content-Disposition` header, so it would return same file every time, with file name provided by user.

Here you can find example:

```java
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/file", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity downloadExecutable(@RequestParam("userId") String userId) throws IOException {
        byte[] file = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/home/genericCopy/generic.exe"));

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=generic_" + userId + ".exe")
                .contentLength(file.length)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(file);
    }
}
```

and result of executing this method:

[image: changed_file_filename]

Comment: Somehow httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName; doesn't work yet the filename appears correctly in the clients' response headers. My original filename is a GUID but should be sent to the client with a human friendly name. No luck with my code though when you click save.